# Print-based debugging

Tags: c++, io, c++17

```
#include <iostream>

const bool DEBUG = false;

template <typename ... Args>
void debug(Args ... args);

template <typename ... Args>
void _debug(Args ... args) {
    std::cout << "[" << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << "] ";
    (std::cout << ... << args) << std::endl;
}

#define debug(args...) if (DEBUG) _debug(args);
```

Suppose you are running ACM or you are somewhere without a well-crafted development environment. You have written some code and wondering what is going wrong.

Goal here is to find out what cause the problem as quickly as possible by placing tracing prints and turn them off all together by preventing code generation for them. So you can  submit your code with `DEBUG = false` and it will not cause any performance issues done by calling `debug(...)`.

Comment: Does that print file name and line number of the caller?

Comment: @MartinR GCC - https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html MSVC - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=vs-2019

Comment: I know what those macros are. But did you try it? – I did (with Xcode/clang on macOS) and the output was the file/number of where the template is define in the debug.hpp file, not where the macro is called in main.cpp.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 13):

Although it's a short function/macro, there are a number of problems here:

- `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are expanded in the function definition, rather than at the call site.  We need an interface that passes those in, so that the macro is

  ```
    #define debug(args...) if (DEBUG) _debug(__FILE__, __LINE__, args);
  ```
- That's a non-standard variadic macro expansion.  The standard way is to write the parameter as `...` and expand it using `__VA_ARGS__`.
- Identifiers in global scope beginning with underscore are reserved for the implementation.  Use a namespace instead (e.g. `debugging::debug`).
- Debug information should go to `std::clog`, not `std::cout`.
- The macro doesn't play nicely in `if`/`else` statements - use the `do`...`while(0)` idiom to make it statement-like.
- Conventional style is to use all-caps for macros (to indicate their dangers) and nothing else.  We have this exactly backwards here, with `debug` and `DEBUG`.

---

## Improved version

```
#include <iostream>

namespace debugging
{
#ifdef ENABLE_DEBUG
    constexpr bool debug = true;
#else
    constexpr bool debug = false;
#endif

    template <typename... Args>
    void print(const char* file, int line, Args... args) {
        (std::clog << "[" << file << ":" << line << "] "
                  << ... << args) << std::endl;
    }
}

#define DEBUG(...)                                              \
    do {                                                        \
        if (debugging::debug)                                   \
            debugging::print(__FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__);  \
    } while (0)
```

And a quick test (that demonstrates that the arguments are evaluated only when we're debugging):

```
int main()
{
    DEBUG("Started main");
    int status = 1;
    DEBUG("Leaving main, status=", status=0);
    return status;
}
```

---

## Addendum

We don't need the `debug` constant - just change the definition of the macro according to whether or not we're debugging:

```
#ifndef ENABLE_DEBUG
#define DEBUG(...)  ((void)0)
#else
#include <iostream>

namespace debugging
{
    template<typename... Args>
    void print(const char* file, int line, Args... args) {
        (std::clog << "[" << file << ":" << line << "] "
                  << ... << args) << std::endl;
    }
}

#define DEBUG(...)  debugging::print(__FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```

Comment: Why `constexpr bool` instead of `const bool` ?

Comment: Fix `error: binary expression in operand of fold-expression` pls. Adding additional parentess around init expr will do the trick.

Comment: I can't remember why I went for `constexpr` there - perhaps just defensiveness.  I also considered `if constexpr` because we might be using variables that we initialize only if debugging - we don't want to trigger warnings in those cases.

Comment: I get no errors with GCC 9.2.0, using `-std=c++2a`.  Adding more parenthesis wouldn't hurt much, but I'm not sure if it's necessary or if your compiler is buggy/old.

Comment: Note: In C++20, prefer [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) over `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`. Prior to C++20, consider [`std::experimental::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/source_location). In fact, with `source_location`, you could even consider making `debug(...)` a (possibly `[[gnu::always_inline]]`) function rather than a macro, possibly allowing lambda-wrapped parameters to allow lazy evaluation.

Comment: @Justin how to prevent generation of any code if you have debug disabled without macros?

Comment: Why bother with defining a `constexpr` variable when you already have a preprocessor flag? Just use that for the conditional... I don't see an advantage in the indirection.

Comment: @CodyGray yeah, try to use `#define ENABLE_DEBUG` inside `if` statement. `ENABLE_DEBUG` have no value.

Comment: I don't see why you need the silly `do/while(0)` idiom.

Comment: @outoftime: Since `debugging::debug` is `constexpr`, you could as well make the test an `if constexpr(debugging::debug)` (in C++17). That would prevent the code generation, and your macro would expand to an empty `do/while` if `debugging::debug` is false. And maybe make `debug` `const constexpr`.

Comment: @ALX23z what do you think this code does?  `if (...) DEBUG(...); else ...`

Comment: @ L.F. to this end you use extra braces `{}` for encapsulation instead of the silly extra 1-length-loop.

Comment: @ALX23z, braces require you to omit the usual semicolon, meaning you can't use the macro like a normal expression - see [this SO answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/154138/4850040), and other answers to the same question.

Answer (score 4):

Each of those insertion operators can be interleaved with other calls in a multi-threaded environment.

Consider building the string in memory first, then making a single call to std::cout.  This approach will also give better behavior with stream buffering disabled as is typical with std::cerr.

Comment: What if program does some IO and I want to tie my debug info to it?

Comment: I'm not too clear on what you're asking, but I think you'd like to know how to send the debug output somewhere else.  You could always pass in the stream object as a parameter.